# How to do image upload with Boothstrap and Django?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with Django. Though I'm good in Python,I'm struggling to figure out some basic things like file uploads/forms in bootstrap. Is there an example to do that?

Also, is there any particular reason for using FileField in Django models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [File Uploads documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

[Django Cripsy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will help you with Bootstrap forms.

The `FileField` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)) will automatically upload and save the file to the model along with giving you various bit of additional functionality such as where to upload to, getting the absolute url for the file and the ability to delete the file from the model object.